# Byte array to float

Tags: c#, bitconverter

I am trying to cast a float into a byte array of length 4, and then back again. But I it doesn's seems to work.

Here's what I've done:

```
byte[] b = BitConverter.GetBytes(90);
float fb = BitConverter.ToSingle(b, 0);
```

I expected fb = 90, but it's 1.26E-43.

I know that my converter is little endian, so I've also tried to reverse the array, like this:

```
byte[] b = BitConverter.GetBytes(90);
Array.Reverse(b);
float fb = BitConverter.ToSingle(b, 0);
```

Then I got the answer fb = 9.0E+15.

Any ideas?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: `90` is an `int`, not a `float`. `90f` is a `float`. In either case, whatever you're doing here is quite possibly the wrong thing to do -- occasionally there is a useful need for converting a `float` into bytes using `BitConverter`, but for most serialization purposes it's actually not the right tool.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`BitConverter.GetBytes(90);` will give you the bytes for the *integer* value of `90`. Since you want the bytes for the `float` value, you need to specify that:

```
BitConverter.GetBytes((float)90.0);
```

or

```
BitConverter.GetBytes(90.0f);
```

Answer (score 6):

You need to change the input on the GetBytes, it's an integer now.

It's now getting the bytes on how the integer is stored and interpretate  as how a float would be stored in memory.

Change it to a float.

Try:

```
byte[] b = BitConverter.GetBytes(90f);  // <-- add an f for floats.
Array.Reverse(b);
float fb = BitConverter.ToSingle(b, 0);
```

Answer (score 6):

`90` is a literal that is interpreted by the compiler as `Int32`, not as `Single`. So you call the wrong overload of `GetBytes()`.

Use: `byte[] b = BitConverter.GetBytes(90f);`

to tell the compiler you want to call `GetBytes(float)`.